# MIDL generates the same file for /env win32 and /env win64

Tags: visual-studio, midl

In Visual Studio, when you compile foo.idl, MIDL generates the proxy information in foo_p.c.

Unfortunately, for Win32 and x64 files, it uses the same filename. For Win32, the file starts with:

```
#if !defined(_M_IA64) && !defined(_M_AMD64)
```

For x64, the file starts with:

```
#if defined(_M_AMD64)
```

When you build for Win32 and then immediately build for x64, it doesn't replace the foo_p.c file, meaning that the project fails to link.

I tried having a pre-build event that deletes the foo_p.c file if it's for the wrong architecture, but VS doesn't even bother to run that step.

How should I get it so that I can build one configuration and then the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the compiler settings for your IDL file to specify a different file name for the output proxy file according to the target platform. (Select Properties on the IDL file, then Configuration Properties / MIDL / Output).

- For Win32 builds, use `foo_p_w32.c`
- For x64 builds, use `foo_p_x64.c`

Then, in your Win32 project settings, exclude the file `foo_p_x64.c` and vice versa for the x64 project.

You need to do the same for the _i.c file, otherwise Visual Studio doesn't seem to rebuild the IDL at all.

Comment: This sucks, but it probably is the only solution since dual stub generation in Visual Studio seems to be broken (see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648537/midl-v7-00-0555-do-not-create-dual-stubs-by-default). Thanks for posting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the configuration changes we use to allow automated builds to work cleanly

Change

```
<Tool
Name="VCMIDLTool"
TypeLibraryName="$(ProjectName).tlb"
OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)"
HeaderFileName="$(ProjectName)_h.h"
DLLDataFileName="$(ProjectName)_dlldata.c"
/>
```

To

```
<Tool
    Name="VCMIDLTool"
    TypeLibraryName="$(InputName).tlb"
    OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)"
    HeaderFileName="$(InputName)_i.h"
    DLLDataFileName="$(InputName)_dlldata.c"
    InterfaceIdentifierFileName="$(InputName)_i.c"
    ProxyFileName="$(InputName)_p.c"
/>
```

and add **$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)** to your C++ Additional Include Directories

e.g.

```
<Tool Name="VCCLCompilerTool" ...
AdditionalIncludeDirectories="...;&quot;$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName);&quot;"
```